# [[base R]] Add T/F column for whether it's the minimum value for each group

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a data frame that looks like this:

| item | weight |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 700 |
| apple | 500 |
| orange | 500 |
| peach | 200 |
| apple | 900 |
| orange | 200 |

What I used to do is use aggregate() to leave only rows with the minimum weight for each item, like:

| item | weight |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 500 |
| peach | 200 |
| orange | 200 |

what I *need* to do is to add a new column, that says whether each row would've been removed:

| item | weight | cheapest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 700 | FALSE |
| apple | 500 | TRUE |
| orange | 500 | FALSE |
| peach | 200 | TRUE |
| apple | 900 | FALSE |
| orange | 200 | TRUE |

I also need to do this while grouping by multiple variables as well.

Is there an easy way to do this using only base R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 <- transform(df, cheapest = ave(weight, item, FUN = min) == weight)
df1
    item weight cheapest
1  apple    700    FALSE
2  apple    500     TRUE
3 orange    500    FALSE
4  peach    200     TRUE
5  apple    900    FALSE
6 orange    200     TRUE
```

Comment: thank you! I forgot to mention in the original post (now edited), but how would this work if you're grouping by multiple variables? like y~x1+x2 ?

Comment: I would try reading the help for `help(ave)` and `help(aggregate)`.

Comment: @Timbo include them in the `ave` function. ie `ave(weight, group1, group2, group3, .., FUN =min)`

Comment: oh you can just list them huh... thank you!

Comment: @Onyambu hi, would it be okay if I asked a follow-up question?
thanks to your help I'm getting things running, but the ave() stage becomes ridiculously slow when I feed two grouping variables into it. There are no errors (other than returning Inf) and yields the right results, just several-hundredfold slow.
Would you perhaps know what the problem is?

Comment: @Timbo you could try using `tapply`. Note that there are other methods better suited for large data.frames, eg data.table

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(item) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(min = if_else(
    weight == min(weight),
    TRUE, FALSE
  ))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   item [3]
  item   weight min  
  <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>
1 apple     700 FALSE
2 apple     500 TRUE 
3 orange    500 FALSE
4 peach     200 TRUE 
5 apple     900 FALSE
6 orange    200 TRUE
```

Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(
  item = c("apple", "apple", "orange", "peach",
           "apple", "orange"),
  weight = c(700, 500, 500, 200, 900, 200)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,
              -6L))
```

To include a 2nd grouping variable, you would just need to include it in the `group_by`.